# Why does spf fail in DMARC report from Google?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spf, dkim, google, dmarc

I recently received a DMARC report from Google alerting me of a few SPF failures with mail originating from IP addresses belonging to Amazon SES. A sample record is as follows (I have replaced our domain with example.com.):

```
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>54.240.27.187</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>example.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </dkim>
      <dkim>
        <domain>amazonses.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>mail.example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
```

Is SPF failing because the `header_from` value is `example.com` while the SPF `domain` value is `mail.example.com`?

We use Amazon WorkMail and Amazon SES to send both manual and automated email. The `From address` is usually `webmaster@example.com`, and we have set our `MAIL FROM` domain to `mail.example.com`. Therefore I am a little puzzled as to why Google would report the `header_from` domain as `example.com` rather than `mail.example.com`. We have set an appropriate SPF record for both `example.com` and `mail.example.com`.

Also, I tried sending test emails to a Gmail address using both Amazon WorkMail and Amazon SES. In both cases, SPF passed, as did DKIM and DMARC.

Comment: It appears the DMARC test failed on SPF, which is not the same as failing an SPF test. You didn't post your DMARC records - do you configure adkim or aspf as strict?

Comment: Yes, both adkim and aspf are set to strict. Our DMARC record is as follows: `v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:webmaster@example.com; ruf=mailto:webmaster@example.com; adkim=s; aspf=s; pct=100`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DMARC compares the [RFC5322](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.6.2).From domain with the SPF-authenticated domain. In your report, we can see that the RFC5322.From domain is `example.com` and the SPF-authenticated domain is `mail.example.com`.

The `aspf` tag is used to indicate whether the DMARC SPF alignment test should be strict (`s`) or relaxed (`r`), with relaxed being the default.

A DMARC record set with `aspf=r` value or no `aspf` tag will verify the RFC5322.From [organizational domain](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7489) matches the SPF-authenticated organizational domain. Your record would pass with this alignment because the organizational domains `example.com` for both.

A DMARC record with `aspf=s` value will verify an exact DNS domain match for the RFC5322.From domain and the SPF-authenticated domain.

The DMARC test has failed because `aspf=s` is configured in your DMARC record and the RFC5322.From domain of `example.com` and the SPF-authenticated domain of `mail.example.com` are not the same.

Comment: Thank you. Btw, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-authentication-dmarc.html says to "Ensure that your sending domain uses a relaxed policy for SPF."  So, although we wanted a strict policy for security, I guess we will need to make this relaxed for now.

Comment: You could set a strict DMARC policy on the subdomain and use that as the From so the domains align and use for mail deemed critical even though it looks, well, how it looks. Assuming that option is compatible with their service.

Comment: Thank you. However, we need to send mail from `webmaster@example.com` and not from `webmaster@mail.example.com`, and the `MAIL FROM` domain must be `mail.example.com`, so I don't think is possible in our case.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it seems Google fails on DKIM when it auto forwards emails from one Gmail account to a second Gmail account.

I guess they at Google should know that in such a case DOMAIN should be original Domain, however they check there own gmail.com Domain. Other option for them would be to recreate New Dkim signatures, removing original ones.

Currently, some of the emails in the Gmail report appear as failed DMARC, due to SPF domain reported for an SPF check (passing on its own) being gmail.com which is different than example.com or the MAIL_FROM set according to AWS SES guide, via DNS record, to be mail.example.com.

Below is a full daily report, where the IP '209.85.220.41' fails DMARC due to using 'gmail.com' domain on the SPF check:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<feedback>
  <report_metadata>
    <org_name>google.com</org_name>
    <email>noreply-dmarc-support@google.com</email>
    <extra_contact_info>https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580</extra_contact_info>
    <report_id>999999999999999999</report_id>
    <date_range>
      <begin>1686441600</begin>
      <end>1686527999</end>
    </date_range>
  </report_metadata>
  <policy_published>
    <domain>example.com</domain>
    <adkim>s</adkim>
    <aspf>r</aspf>
    <p>reject</p>
    <sp>quarantine</sp>
    <pct>100</pct>
    <np>quarantine</np>
  </policy_published>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>209.85.220.41</source_ip>
      <count>6</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>fail</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>example.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>AWS_CNAME_AUTHENTICATION_SELECTOR</selector>
      </dkim>
      <dkim>
        <domain>amazonses.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>AWS_OWN_AUTHENTICATION_SELECTOR</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>gmail.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>54.240.8.60</source_ip>
      <count>2</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>example.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>AWS_CNAME_AUTHENTICATION_SELECTOR</selector>
      </dkim>
      <dkim>
        <domain>amazonses.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>AWS_OWN_AUTHENTICATION_SELECTOR</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>mail.example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>54.240.8.176</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>example.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>AWS_CNAME_AUTHENTICATION_SELECTOR</selector>
      </dkim>
      <dkim>
        <domain>amazonses.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>AWS_OWN_AUTHENTICATION_SELECTOR</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>mail.example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>54.240.8.237</source_ip>
      <count>2</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>example.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>AWS_CNAME_AUTHENTICATION_SELECTOR</selector>
      </dkim>
      <dkim>
        <domain>amazonses.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>AWS_OWN_AUTHENTICATION_SELECTOR</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>mail.example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>54.240.8.13</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>example.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>AWS_CNAME_AUTHENTICATION_SELECTOR</selector>
      </dkim>
      <dkim>
        <domain>amazonses.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>AWS_OWN_AUTHENTICATION_SELECTOR</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>mail.example.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
</feedback>
```

Comment: Exactly my issue, what an edge case, thank you.